# Mixed cycling loops in ansible

Tags: redis, yaml, ansible, jinja2

I inherit an ansible role (on which I don't have control), which role is to install a redis, in clustering.

To do that, I have to provide a variable which looks like this in a hard-coded defaults/main.yml :

```
r_cluster:
  - "192.168.0.2:6380 192.168.0.1:6379"
  - "192.168.0.3:6380 192.168.0.2:6379"
  - "192.168.0.1:6380 192.168.0.3:6379"
```

So, my goal is to build such a variable, not hard-coded, but extracted from my hosts file.

On the other hand, I have my hosts group configured :

```
[mygroup]
redis1 ansible_host=192.168.0.1 ...
redis2 ansible_host=192.168.0.2 ...
redis3 ansible_host=192.168.0.3 ...
```

The tricky part is to build a variable like "r_cluster" from this group with this sort of cycling !

The closest I have is :

```
- name: define my hosts list
  set_fact: h_item="{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_fqdn'] }}:6380 {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_fqdn'] }}:6379"
  with_items: "{{groups['mygroup']}}"
  register: h_result

- name: transform it into the final r_cluster
  set_fact: r_cluster="{{ h_result.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.h_item') | list }}"
```

which outputs :

```
"r_cluster": [
        "192.168.0.1:6380 192.168.0.1:6379",
        "192.168.0.2:6380 192.168.0.2:6379",
        "192.168.0.3:6380 192.168.0.3:6379"
    ]
```

Of course, the IPs are not cycling in the output.

I didn't find any "item+1", or looping "from the second element and ending to the first element", ...

Is there a way to do this, instead of building a full algorithm (which would be not very convenient to do in yaml) ?

I don't think I can use {% %} to build code, since this seems to be allowed only in templates, and templates are irrelevant here, I have to build a variable (to be consumed by the partner role).

Comment: Why do you want to calculate the IPs? Why don't you simply add another host-var which defines the related IP:Port? What are these IP:Port-pairs actually? Are those master-slave replication paths?

Comment: Each master hosts the slave of another node. This is a "black box" : another partner manages the redis cluster (with this choice) and they provide an ansible role with variables to submit. I fill these variables, and send them to the "ansible redis black-box role". And to do that, they require us to fill such a variable.

Comment: Yes, but why do you need to do something like item+1? In the host vars of each host simply define a variable slave_host. You could even do it in your group where you have defined the ips. `redis1 ansible_host=192.168.0.1 slave_host=192.168.0.3`. I'll post a complete example as an answer, maybe it then gets clearer what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of cycling through the IPs you can define the slave nodes explicitly in the group-vars.

```
[mygroup]
redis1 ansible_host=192.168.0.1 slave_host=192.168.0.3
redis2 ansible_host=192.168.0.2 slave_host=192.168.0.1
redis3 ansible_host=192.168.0.3 slave_host=192.168.0.2
```

This var you can use in your loop:

```
- name: define my hosts list
  set_fact: h_item="{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_fqdn'] }}:6380 {{ hostvars[item]['slave_host'] }}:6379"
  with_items: "{{groups['mygroup']}}"
  register: h_result
```

Comment: Sometimes, other eyes can provide a so simple solution by looking it with another angle. Thanks udondan!